# HTTP Get Response parsing in java and store in a string

Tags: java

i have this below response from a HTTP Get request

```
RESPONSE=You are about to purchase abcd package for 20 usd. Charge :1usd&encoding=0&SessionOp=end
```

I'm trying to get only `"You are about to purchase abcd package for 20 usd. Charge :1usd"` to a string in java so that i can display it to the customer, but i'm not sure how.

Any help would be appreciated. thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Comment: `response.split("Charge")[0].split("RESPONSE=")[1]` will give you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an indexof and a substring, as shown in this example :

```
String response = "You are about to purchase abcd package for 20 usd. Charge 1usd&encoding=0&SessionOp=end";
String newresponse = response;
int index = response.indexOf('&');
if (index != -1) {
    newresponse = newresponse.substring(0, index);
}
return newresponse;
```

Here, newreponse will contains the split String.